# Why is the value in this js code not changed?

Tags: javascript

I was looking at this javascript code:

```js
var a = {i: 0};
var b = 0;

function change(a, b) {
  a.i++;
  b++;
}
change(a, b);

console.log(a, b);
```

You would expect to be logged: {i:1} 1 . It actually returns:
{i:1} 0?
Why is b=0 and not b=1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `b` is a *parameter* inside `change` - inside `change`, `b` refers to the *local* variable, and when the local variable is reassigned, that has no effect on the `b` outside.

Either always refer to `b` as a global variable:

```js
var a = {i: 0};
var b = 0;

function change(a) {
  a.i++;
  b++;
}
change(a);

console.log(a, b);
```

Or return `b` from `change`, and assign the outer `b` to the result of `change`:

```js
var a = {i: 0};
var b = 0;

function change(a, b) {
  a.i++;
  b++;
  return b;
}
b = change(a, b);

console.log(a, b);
```

(if you need to return and reassign multiple variables, return an object or array:

```js
var a = {i: 0};
var b = 0;
var c = 0;

function change(a, b, c) {
  a.i++;
  b++;
  c++;
  return { b, c };
}
({b, c} = change(a, b, c));

console.log(a, b, c);
```

)

Comment: The a variable has changed though?

Comment: ... or pass b inside an object

Comment: @bierhier `a` is an *object* - when `a` is passed, you're only passing a *reference* to the same `a` object in memory, so when `a` is mutated inside the function, it's changed on the outside as well.

Answer (score 1):

You're shadowing your variable `a` in your function header.

```
function change() {
    a.i++;
    b++;
  }
```

will work.